# FusionAuth - Invite based user on-boarding with social logins

Tags: oauth-2.0, fusionauth

We create users with their email address. We send email to each user with  a link to change password api with `changePasswordId`. When user clicks the link, he will be redirected to change password screen where he can set the password and access the application. This works.

But, now we want to allow users to register with their social Idps upon receiving invitation/verification email. Can't see any fusionauth documentation on this part.

Questions are as follows

1. How to let user select their social Idp while verifying their email?
2. Can a user have multiple logins with different Idps for one application in FusionAuth?
3. Is there any linking api which links all external user accounts with their fusionauth user account?

The flow we are expecting is :

```
 Invite User ->  User clicks link -> User will be presented with set 
 password and social logins-> User chooses google -> Google
 authenticates user and returns token back to fusion auth -> fusion
 auth links user's google account with already created (invited) user
 account. -> Next time user logs in with google account -> Fusion auth
 identifies the user and allows him to access the application.
```

**Updated :**
Let me try to explain our situation and need, with less focus on the password setup task:

We need to set up new users that are associated with google based education accounts on custom school domains. Teachers and students that might have addresses like `first.last@middle.school.com`  We need to take the class roster from Google Classroom, initialize accounts for each student in our backend via our API which also creates FusionAuth user and app registrations for each.

Schools don't often want kids setting passwords on vendor sites. When we send the account confirmation / verification email to the new cohort of students they would ideally be directed to the approved and configured method for that domain (perhaps Google, Microsoft, other SAML or password). If we can't get selective about the confirmation method shown after the student provides her invited email address then we could present multiple confirmation options on the same screen and let the teacher direct the students to the correct choice.

But in summary we need to avoid requiring password setup and support confirmation with the invited social account when required by the school.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your use case correctly, what you want is to add the "Login with Google buttons" to the Setup Password workflow. This is different than the Email Verification workflow, so if you are looking for a way to log users in with their social profiles during Email Verification, that's something completely different. In fact, I don't think that is a use case because after the user verifies their email, they need to log in again and they can do that using their social profile.

Unfortunately, FusionAuth doesn't fully support the ability to allow someone to use the Setup Password workflow using a social login. It might be possible though using the Email Templates and Theme editor in FusionAuth. I haven't tested this, but you could try it and see if it works.

What you would do is to pass in a URL parameter to show the social login buttons during the Setup Password workflow. This would be something you could do in the email template for Setup Password like this:

```
Click this link to setup your password:
<a href="https://example.com/password/change/${changePasswordId}?showSocial=true">
Setup Password
</a>
```

Then, using the Theme editor in FusionAuth, you would add some code in to show the buttons like this (the `??` part is to handle when the parameter is missing):

```
[#if showSocial?? && showSocial]
  show social buttons here
[/#if]
```

You could give that a try and see if it works for your use case. If it doesn't work, you can always open a feature request for this on our GitHub issue tracker and we can see if it receives enough upvotes to get on the roadmap. You can also engage FusionAuth professional services to build this feature for you as well.

For your other questions, you can have as many logins with external IdPs as you want for a single user. The user is unique by their email address.

I'm not sure what you mean by "linking api", but if a user logs in with an external IdP, their tokens from those external providers are stored on the user object. You can look up those values and then call third-party APIs with their access_tokens.

**UPDATE 8/27/2019**

Ah yes. The social login buttons do require all of the OAuth parameters, so this solution won't work because those parameters aren't part of the Setup Password workflow.

I guess I'm confused on how this actually works and whether or not this is a workflow FusionAuth should be handling. Social logins aren't generally used for account verification. They are normally used for account creation. For example, you could just send the student to FusionAuth before their account is created, they login with their Google classroom account, and then they have a FusionAuth account. Is there any reason the student can just login in after their account is created? Is that not essentially the same thing?

Could you do something where students that have accounts in Google Classroom are created in FusionAuth with a randomly generated 32 character password (for security) since they will be logging in with Google regardless. You can then just send them an email with a standard login link.

For students that login in with a username and password to FusionAuth directly, send them a Setup Password email. This will let them pick their own password.

In terms of account Linking, FusionAuth links accounts automatically based on email address (the unique login identifier actually). Therefore, you don't need to call any extra API to associate the social login with a user.

I might still not be clearly understanding the use case, so feel free to contact us directly using the form on our website. We might need to setup a web conference to discuss your needs in detail.

Comment: Thanks @Brian.  I updated my question with better description of our use case. Please have a look.

Comment: w.r.t `linking api` i was referring to the similar one like this - https://auth0.com/docs/link-accounts

Comment: Brian is there any chance the Change Password template is set to ignore URL parameters like showSocial? It also seems that we need access to client_id as an argument to show social buttons but this is also not set (all the form's hidden fields are empty except changePasswordId).